# Android SQLite shuts down app without exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Can someone help me with my problem? Im trying to implement SQLite database into my app, but anytime i run the activity that uses my database class, it shuts down my application (its still running in background tho and when i started, the whole app restarts). I dont get any errors or exceptions, so I dont know how to track the problem.

Here is my database class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "events.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_ALLEVENTS = "allevents";

public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
public static final String COLUMN_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String COLUMN_STARTDATE = "startdate";
public static final String COLUMN_ENDDATE = "enddate";
public static final String COLUMN_PICTUREURL = "pictureurl";
public static final String COLUMN_URL = "url";
public static final String COLUMN_SAVED = "saved";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    //3rd argument to be passed is CursorFactory instance
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_ALLEVENTS + "("
            + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_SUBTITLE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_STARTDATE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_ENDDATE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_PICTUREURL + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_URL + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_SAVED + " TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ALLEVENTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
  }
}
```

And the only thing I do in my activity is this:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

---

// UPDATE (SOLVED NOW):

I fixed it today, it looks like somehow the problem was in the project itself, because i tried to create a new project and copy paste the same code there and run it, and it started to work normally. I have no logical explanation for this, but the logcat also helped me a lot in the new project, so my suggestion for anyone with similar problem is to create a new project and test your queries there, because apparently Android Studio does not show all errors sometimes. Good luck!

Comment: Apparently the code looks proper. Can you try by removing the ";" from the end - + COLUMN_SAVED + " TEXT)"; Also, check the logcat, there might be some exception.

Comment: Can you post your logcat when the crash happens?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in the logcat, there is just one line that is added after this happens but its not related to this topic

Comment: I tried that already, didnt help as well :/ there is nothing in logcat, no error, no exception

Comment: Okay. Make sure you are not filtering by any tag in logcat.

Comment: I have encountered instances where my logcat won't display anything, usually that gets fixed if I close & open Android Studio. I would try that and see if you can get something in the logcat then.

Comment: I have set my filter to show only selected application, and the another menu says Verbose

Comment: @DanielK just restarted and looked, there is nothing new, still the same

Comment: Can you add the activity that uses the database then?

Comment: The `;` is only **useless**, but **not harmful**.

Comment: Its an empty activity, there is only initialization, floating button onclick listener, and then the last code line from my original topic.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer instead of editing it into your question. It is perfectly OK to accept your own answer to mark your question as solved.

Comment: I guess you should have used a `Clean / Rebuild`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new database variable in this way

```
SQLiteDatabase db=new SQLiteDatabase();
this.db=db;
```

and run the onCreate() method on the new db variable.
You will have to create a new instance in every function too.

Comment: 1. Cant create the SQLiteDatabase because i cant access it as its not public... 2. What db should i assign to it?

Comment: try to check whether the sql database file is getting created or not. use eclipse's file explorer for that . It maybe the case that your file is not getting created.